# Cannot assign INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE to constexpr HANDLE when making typedefs for Winapi

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, cl

I made the following code to make my code less ugly and to not have to worry about too aggressively separating windows implementations from the rest of the code.

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "windows.h"

namespace RawHttp
{
namespace Win
{

using Bool = BOOL;
using Handle = HANDLE;
using Dword = DWORD;
constexpr const Handle Null = NULL;
constexpr const Handle InvalidHandle = static_cast<Handle>(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
}
}
#else
namespace RawHttp
{
namespace Win
{

using Bool = bool;
using Handle = void *;
using Dword = unsigned long;
constexpr const Handle Null = nullptr;
constexpr const Handle InvalidHandle = (Handle)(long long)-1;
}
}
#endif //_WIN32
```

If included in a C++ file, it fails to compile in Visual Studio:

```
windows\windowstypes.h(14): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
windows\windowstypes.h(14): note: failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value
```

In G++, it compiles just fine. What does that error even mean?

How to properly cast the window's `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to `constexpr void*`, and how to do the same in the non windows branch of the code above?

My Visual Studio Version is 15.9.18.

Comment: You don't need to type cast `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, its already typed as `HANDLE`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think so too, I only added the cast after the error appeared hoping it would fix it.

Comment: On a side note, `(long long)-1` can be written as `-1LL` instead

Comment: TL;DR; from the duplicate: g++ is wrong, MSVC (and clang) are right: you can't `reinterpret_cast` (or C-style cast) to a `constexpr` pointer type.

Comment: @AdrianMole So why does the static cast also fail? And in general, how can I get the code to work for both windows and non-windows branch? I am getting the same error in both, which is to be expected as per the linked QA. So what is the correct approach there?

Comment: The static cast fails because the definition of the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` macro already includes a C-style cast. But it will also fail without that, because you can't static cast a (non-zero) integer literal to a pointer. How to get round it is a trickier matter.

Comment: One possibility is to just remove the `constexpr` and leave your `InvalidHandle` just as a (static) `const`.